# connect to a database using vbscript in UFT

Tags: sql, vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to connect to database using a test account for running my automation

```
 connStr.open "provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=SEACITMFGCM11.itlab.local;User Id=" & userName & "; Password=******; Database=MfgDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

my username and this test account has access to database, so i was able to connect without any issues. But my collegue who doesn't have access to database try to run my automation and this connstr.open is still using windows authentication user to login and failing.

In the watch i saw the connection string as

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=OLYMPUS\ITQAAUTOTEST01;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=SEA-L-00020821;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;"
```

I don't see the password in the connection string.

How can i make the code to connect to the database using my test account OLYMPUS\ITQAAUTOTEST01 and not my account

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Trusted_Connection=Yes" in your connection string is telling it to use the credentials of the currently logged in user, ignoring the username and password you specified in the connection string. Remove the "Trusted_Connection=Yes".

Comment: Thanks Troy. i figured that out. now i gave no to the trusted connection, its taking test account information and not able to connect.

I still see the connection string doesn't show the password in the watch window. is it for security reasons, i don't see the password?

Comment: Correct. You will not see the password in the connection string. I would guess that the user doesn't have permissions. Are the permissions in SQL being granted to the user or a group?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect to the database using ssms with that userid and password.

Comment: actually now i understood that you can either connect windows authentication or as a sql user. So basically its not possible to connect with test account and unless this test account is added as sql user in the database. Thanks for all your help. You can close this question

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. There is no "close", but if my answer helped just "accept" it by clicking on the check-mark. Thanks